# My iText RemoteGoto doesn't jump to the correct destination

Tags: hyperlink, itext, goto

In my iText document I'm writing some text about my entity which shall reference to an occurence in another PDF document.
There are multiple ways of doing this with iText:

```
static String externalLinkPrefix = "external_entity_";
String externalFile = "anotherPdf.pdf";
Chunk entity = new Chunk("name");
// use the plain remoteGoto() method
chunk.setRemoteGoto(externalFile, externalLinkPrefix + entity.getIdentifier());
// or use the PdfAction
chunk.setAction(PdfAction.gotoRemotePage(externalFile, externalLinkPrefix + entity.getIdentifier(), false, true);

// later on create the destination in the other file
Paragraph entityReference = new Paragraph(new Chunk("name")
     .setLocalDestination(externalLinkPrefix + entity.getIdentifier());
```

However when I click the created link it takes me to the beginning of the second document signalling that it did not find the destination.

I double-checked wheter the link 'keys' are the same and they are.

What does iText or the PDF Reader hinder finding the destination?

Comment: Can you share the PDFs? That way we can examine the GoToR link in the document with the link and the named destination in the document with the reference.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. See my edit for the links.
I'd like to add the relevant parts of the pdf stream in my question but I found a little quirk in the documents. In the link-source-document there are multiple GoToRs when there should be only one (probably an error by me). Can you point out the relevant portions of the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to describe a named destination in PDF:

1. You define the destination using a PDF string (preferred since PDF 1.2),
2. You define the destination using a PDF name (original in PDF 1.1).

In your case, create a Names tree that stores the destination as a PDF string:

[image]

Do you see `foo_section_2`? That's clearly a PDF string. You are using the preferred way to define a named destination because `setLocalDestination()` is programmed that way in iText.

However, you use a `PdfAction.gotoRemotePage()` method that isn't complete. Based on your PDF, I assume that you create a reference to a named destination using a PDF name (`/foo_section_2`):

[image]

You can see that `/foo_section_2` is a name because it starts with a `/`. There is no named destination that is defined using a name in the target file, hence the destination can't be found.

You should use the `gotoRemotePage()` method like this:

```
PdfAction.gotoRemotePage(externalFile, externalLinkPrefix + entity.getIdentifier(),
    false, true)
```

The third parameter of the `gotoRemotePage()` method should be `false` to make sure that you create a link to a named destination that uses a PDF string instead of a PDF name (which is probably what you're doing).

For some reason, Acrobat thinks that grunddaten doesn't have any named destinations:

[image]

This is confirmed when I look at the Navigations Tab, but when I try to add a named destination, I get "There was a problem reading this document (15)." I have no clue as to what 15 refers to.

[image]

Running Preflight, I get more info:

[image]

This tells me that the NameTreeRoot isn't constructed correctly. I'll have to investigate what's wrong. It works when I create a document with named destinations, see [RemoteGoto](https://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/RemoteGoto). I've just tested it and ran Preflight and it works perfectly. I have no idea what goes wrong in your file...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However I have to admit that I made a mistake when I removed irrelevant things in my code.. 
I edited my question to include the complete iText API call of gotoRemotePage(), I've already used the 3rd (=false) and 4th(=true) parameter.
I'm creating the destination by the call included in the above example. I also tried switching the isName from true to false, none made it work.
I might be naive but I assumed that making sure the gotos 'name' are equal would do the trick.  What else might be wrong?

Comment: After putting the problem aside for a few days, I just tried to make it work, et voila it just works. I didn't change anything [obvious to me].
I am using the approach recommended by you. Thanks for your help and insights :-)

Comment: @RobertNorden Thank you for the feedback. I still had an open ticket on my personal TODO list regarding this issue (I looked at it a couple of times, but I just didn't see what was wrong). I'll close it for now.

Comment: Argh, I probably found the reason. Meanwhile I switched from iText 5.5.6 (see your screenshot) to 5.5.7!
I just switched it back again to test it. In 5.5.6 it does not work, in 5.5.7 it works!